# Calcular cada subtotal das linhas da tabela e tambem o totalPedido, sendo as linhas dinamicas, ou seja, mesmo id

Tags: javascript, laravel, matemática

o objetivo é obter os subtotais em cada linha e o totalPedido. Está acontecendo isso parcialmente. Duas coisas mim incomodando:
1 - mesmo mostrando o resultado nos subtotais, no log fica exibindo a mensagem
    :create:236 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at subtotalizar (create:236)"

2 - O totalPedido somente é calculado quando é o último item da iteração. E não soma, apenas concatena. Se eu coloco ParseInt( .. não calcula e nem soma.

gostaria da ajuda para resolver esses problemas, ou seja:
1 - Calcular os subtotais sem exibir essa mensagem de erro no log
2 - calcular o totalPedido sendo a soma de todos eles.

Segue o blade:

```
  <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Produto</th>
        <th scope="col">Preço</th>
        <th scope="col">Quantidade</th>
      </tr>    
    @foreach ($produtosFazenda as $produtos)
    <div class="fazenda">
    <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="hidden" class="produtoid"  name = "produtoid[]" 
            placeholder="{{$produtos->id}}" value="{{$produtos->id}}" aria-label="produto" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" >
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>{{$produtos->descricao}}</p></td>
        <td>
          <input type="Number" class="valor" name="preco[]" readonly
            placeholder="{{$produtos->preco}}" value="{{$produtos->preco}}"  aria-label="preco" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" >
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="Number" class="quantidade" name="quantidade[]"  
            placeholder="0" aria-label="quantidade"  aria-describedby="basic-addon1" onblur = "subtotalizar()" />
        </td> 
        <td>
          <input type="Number" class="subtotal" id="subtotal" name = "subtotal[]"  readonly 
            placeholder="0" aria-label="subtotal"  aria-describedby="basic-addon1" />
        </td>
  @endforeach
      </tr>
  </table>

  <input type="Number" class="totalPedido" id="totalPedido" name = "totalPedido" value="00" readonly 
  placeholder="0" aria-label="totalPedido"  aria-describedby="basic-addon1" />

@csrf
    <input class ="btn btn-primary" type ="submit" value= "Enviar Pedido">
</form>
      </div>
```

```
    function subtotalizar(){
      var itensqtd = document.getElementsByClassName("quantidade");
      var itensvlr = document.getElementsByClassName("valor");
      var itenssubtotal = document.getElementsByClassName("subtotal");
      var totalP = document.getElementById("totalPedido");
          for (var i=0; i<=itensvlr.length; i++){
              itenssubtotal[i].value = parseInt(itensqtd[i].value) * parseInt(itensvlr[i].value); 
              totalP.value += parseInt(itenssubtotal[i].value);
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Calcular os subtotais sem exibir essa mensagem de erro no log**

Este erro no log está ocorrendo porque você está fazendo ele percorrer mais itens do array do que deveria, por exemplo, se existirem 11 itens na sua tabela, o loop irá tentar percorrer 12. Pra resolver isso é só trocar a condição do loop de `<=` para `<`.

A linha do for deveria ficar assim: `for (var i=0; i < itensvlr.length; i++){`

**2. Calcular o totalPedido sendo a soma de todos eles.**

A soma do total não está ocorrendo porque, muito embora você esteja usando o parseInt, o valor de totalP.value é uma string por ser o campo do html. Para contornar isso é possível utilizar uma variável acima do loop contendo a soma atual.

Com isso o código final deveria se parecer com isso:

```
function decimal (valor, casas = 2) {
    return Number(Number(valor).toFixed(casas));
}

function subtotal () {
    var itensqtd = document.getElementsByClassName("quantidade");
    var itensvlr = document.getElementsByClassName("valor");
    var itenssubtotal = document.getElementsByClassName("subtotal");
    var totalP = document.getElementById("total");

    var vTotal = 0;

    for (var i=0; i < itensvlr.length; i++){
        itenssubtotal[i].value = decimal(Number(itensqtd[i].value) * Number(itensvlr[i].value));
        vTotal += decimal(itenssubtotal[i].value);
        totalP.value = total;
    }
}
```

OBS: Coloquei também uma função para facilitar o cálculo com o valor ou a quantidade em decimal

Comment: Muito obrigado pelos esclarecimentos.